# Load a svg file(xml) and extract specific information using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg

I am trying to get a svg file using jquery/javascript
svg example:

```
<svg width="111" height="123" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" x="1.5" y="1.5"width="108.00001" height="119.99999" id="svg_1" rescale="none" move="Static"/>
  <text text_pos="midcenter" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Fantasy" font-size="14" id="Actor Role name" y="68" x="55" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" rescale="none" move="Static">Actor Role</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

And using something like this to extract the data from a file

```
     $.get(file_url, function(data) {
              var teste=data;
           },'xml')// or use text instead of xml
```

then get all the elements like rect or text
and say get something like(exclude the inside ' ' just to know where the values come from):

'Element' rect, 'rescale' none, 'move' static

and for text(exclude the inside ' '): 
'Element' rect, 'rescale' none, 'move' static, 'text_pos' midcenter ,'id' Actor Role name, 'node value' Actor Role

**RESOLVED-PARTIALLY**

```
    $.get(file_url, function(data) {
       var teste=data; //all data
       rect1=$('<g>').append($(teste).find("text").attr("id")).html();
       rect2=rect1+"-"+$('<g>').append($(teste).find("text").attr("text_pos")).html();
       alert(rect2);
    });
    alert(rect2);
```

Issue found it doesnt pass the variable data, outside that $.get

first `alert(rect2);` gives the correct data

second `alert(rect2);` gives me undefined

anyone knows why it isn't giving a global variable :X
already try making the variable outside but doesn't work also

well sorry for this forgot to change the coment :f now its correct

Comment: You don't have `alert(rect1)` in your code, just 2 `alert(rect2)`. It's perfectly normal that the 2nd is undefined since : 1- it's defined in the above function 2- it's defined in an ajax callback (which is... asynchrone)

Comment: i changed the code area but had forgot to change the rest, now it`s correct

Answer (score 2):

This is how I've been loading the SVG file:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $.get("path-to-svg.svg", null, function(data){
        var svgNode = $("svg", data);
        var docNode = document.adoptNode(svgNode[0]);
        var pageNode = $("#element-to-hold-svg");
        pageNode.html(docNode);
    }, 'xml');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the code found here: [Ajax or JavaScript: Changing Style According to Server Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443374/ajax-or-javascript-changing-style-according-to-server-response) with

```
    var XMLrequest = newXMLHttpRequest(); // new XML request
    XMLrequest.open("GET", myURL, false); // URL of the SVG file on server
    XMLrequest.send(null); // get the SVG file

    var mySVG = XMLrequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
```

So you can now use `jQuery(mySVG)` or pure javascript to extract the properties.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

In my case the svg data includes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

So For me getting the SVG was done as so:

```
var xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="2" height="2"><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 1 1 l 1 1"/></svg>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$svg = $xml.find( "svg" );
```

Though it was asked about the 'g' element. Ran a quick test and was not able to get results with your provided data, regardless the following sample code should help:

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><\!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="5cm" height="5cm">  <desc>Two groups, each of two rectangles</desc>  <g id="group1" fill="red">    <rect x="1cm" y="1cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>    <rect x="3cm" y="1cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>  </g>  <g id="group2" fill="blue">    <rect x="1cm" y="3cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>    <rect x="3cm" y="3cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>  </g><\!-- Show outline of canvas using \'rect\' element -->  <rect x=".01cm" y=".01cm" width="4.98cm" height="4.98cm"  fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".02cm"/></svg>',
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$g = $xml.find( "g" );
console.log($g);
```

SVG sample data obtained from http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups