# JQuery - Change svg color in a <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to change the color of a svg image.
The Problem is, that the svg is inside of an image tag:

```
<img src="image.svg" />
```

I tried this code:

```
var _currentFill = "#ffffff";
$svg = $(".thumbnail-image");
$("#face", $svg).attr('style', "fill:"+_currentFill);
```

I alsow tried to enlarge the image brightness with css, but it didn't became a clear white.

Is somebody out there with a soloution for my problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Think svg has to be [embedded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/SVG_and_CSS) for styling.

Comment: You can't access the contents of an img tag.

Comment: @Turnip and there is no jquery soloution ?

Comment: Check [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909343/load-a-svg-filexml-and-extract-specific-information-using-javascript), or similar, search for `jquery load svg xml` on google. If you manage to load the xml, than replace your `img` tag with it and style as you want. Think you may have cross-origin issues, maybe have to use server-side script.